# Lower bound on a function of probability distribution

Tags: probability, number-theory, random

Let 
$$
\gamma = \frac{1}{\sum_{y}f(y)W(y)},
$$

where

$$
f(y) = 1 + e^{-|y|}
$$

and $W(y)$ is a probability distribution (unknown) with $y \in \mathcal{Y}$ arbitrary but discrete, and $x \in \{0,1\}$. I want to calculate a lower bound on $\gamma$. I came up with one lower bound as follows:
\begin{aligned}
\gamma &= \frac{1}{\sum_{y}f(y)W(y)}\\
&\ge  \frac{1}{\sum_{y}f(y)}, \because W(y) \le 1,  \forall y \in \mathcal{Y}\\
\end{aligned}
I wanted a tighter bond than this. Any ideas or references are appreciated. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

$1 \lt f(y) \le 2$

so  $1=\sum_{y}W(y) \lt \sum_{y}f(y)W(y) \le \sum_{y}2W(y) =2$

so $\frac12 \le \gamma \lt 1$.

Comment: Thanks! I completely overlooked that! Also, can I ask a related question here or should I post it separately as a new question?

Comment: @Aitezaz It depends on the question, but probably best to ask a new one and link back to this one.

Answer (score 0):

As $$f(y) = 1 + e^{-|y|}\leq 2$$
then
$$E[f(y)]=\sum_{y} f(y)W(y)\leq \sum_{y} 2 ~W(y)=2 $$
Hence
$$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sum_{y}f(y)W(y)}\geq \frac{1}{2}$$